# Cannot pull same image after aborting Docker pull once: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting

Tags: docker

After aborting a `docker pull`, when I attempt to repeat the same to let it continue it results in this error:

> Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting.

There is no other active Docker client at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the docker client issued a command to the docker daemon. Then you killed the client by pushing ctrl + c (or it just died for some reason). This means the daemon is till downloading layer/image but the client is just not blocking waiting for it. In a second client invocation if you try to download the same image your get the error message shown above.

Normally things just resolve themselves when after a while when the daemon is done downloading the image. However, if it gets into a bad state restarting the docker daemon (or boot2docker VM) will fix the issue.

Comment: This is not a solution for all environments, I'm afraid. We've been running into this issue with docker 1.8.2 quite regularly – and this is the production environment where restarting the docker daemon is simply not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the download looks like freezed, once you had to abort `docker pull` and then started it again:

[image]

In this case it also is the only solution to restart the docker daemon. :-/